# Saving animation with keyframe inserting location and rotation

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, keyframes, unity

While saving an animation clip with keyframe of armature pose, should I select all armatures and insert location and rotation or can I just insert changed armature's location and rotation?

I selected all bones and inserted new pose. Working great. But doesn't seem to be the optimized solution. Character animations are being used for games in Unity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert the new animation to the keyframe of the armature who is changed. You can actually keyframe a new rotation of just one bone of an armature, so if you modified a bone rotation in pose mode you can then press I to insert keyframe and then choose rotation, and this will insert a new keyframe for the rotation of this bone.

I attached a .blend file where two armatures are there and adjusted the bone rotation of specific bones.

[image]

Comment: So I don't have to select all bone pose and insert and it will work same?

Comment: yes, you don't have to. You can insert the new rotation/location/scale for one bone pose and it should work. Give it a go and let me know if you have any problem.

Comment: @SP. I've added a .blend file to my answer as an example. Let me know if it works or not?